# Creating txt file in python - pywin32

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a txt file using PythonWin and when I run it, nothing happens.

```
import sys, os
import wmi
import math

computer = wmi.WMI()
computer_info = computer.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
os_info = computer.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]
proc_info = computer.Win32_Processor()[0]
gpu_info = computer.Win32_VideoController()[0]

os_name = os_info.Name.encode('utf-8').split(b"|")[0]
os_version = ' '.join([os_info.Version, os_info.BuildNumber])
system_ram = math.ceil(float(os_info.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / 1048576)

processorInfo = (proc_info.Name.split(" CPU")[0])
processorInfo = processorInfo.replace("(R)", "")
processorInfo = processorInfo.replace("(TM)", "")

operatingSystem = (os_name.decode('utf8'))
operatingVersion = (os_version.split(" ")[0])
memoryInfo = ('{0} GB'.format(system_ram))
graphicsCard = (gpu_info.Name)

hardwareList = [operatingSystem, operatingVersion, processorInfo, graphicsCard, memoryInfo]

f = open('user_specs.txt', 'w+')
f.write(str(hardwareList))
f.close()
```

As I run it all I get is "Script 'my file location' returned exit code 0", but no file was created anywhere.

Comment: Try specifying a full path name for the file, if using the Windows path separator  \ then make sure you use a *raw string*.

Comment: *pywin32* has nothing to do with file creation. Note that the file is created in the current folder. You can see that by adding a `print(os.getcwd())` statement in your script.